# Why are the Stratosians allowed to be members of the Federation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In *[TOS: The Cloud Minders](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cloud_Minders_(episode))* we have the planet Ardana with two dramatically distinct peoples, the people of Stratos, the cloud city and the Troglytes who work like slaves.

The people of Stratos are members of the Federation, so:

- Does the Federation allow slavery?
- Did the Federation simply not know this fact?
- Did the Federation simply not know this fact *because the Stratosian leaders lied about it?*

**Why is Stratos allowed to be a member of the Federation?**

Comment: Civilizations don't join the Federation. societies do.  If a government that rules an entire species and planet asks to join the Federation, the entire area of that species's former civilization will join the Federation.  But by the time a society applies to join the Federation, its former species wide civilization will already be starting to merge into interstellar civilization, just as the former civilizations on Earth have all merged into the Earth civilization.  Societies that apply to join the Federation are all at least partially part of interstellar civilization.

Comment: @M.A.Golding That sounds like the beginning of an Answer, rather than a Comment to improve the Question. However, if you do expand it into one, you might want to clarify your distinction between "society" and "civilization", which I find slightly confusing.

Comment: True, I'm french, so I'm not aware about subtil distinction between the two words :)

Answer (score 2):

Does the Federation allow slavery? No.  In the Ds9 era Bajor even going back to mere castes would have been a deal breaker. Ds9 "Accession"

The Federation ignore this fact because they don't ask?  At least in the TOS era this appears to be true.  Very little is known about Vulcan biology or Stratos society.

The Federation ignore this fact because the people of Stratos lie?  If they are lying the Federation isn't ignoring it because they don't know.  They may be failing to investigate.  But even in TNG "the Hunted" a societal mismatch was not discovered until fairly late in the admission process.

Comment: I use the word "ignore" like "don't know". Apparently it have a different meaning. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answers for the three first questions. I asked 4 instead of one... it's not fair;)
You're right, I forgot this point in DS9. It's not the same century but it's fine enough for me.
It's true, sometimes, an alien must explain a specificity of his species to a Starfleet character, but I'm not sure this fact tell us if the Federation ask or not if a civilization meets certain eligibility criteria to join the Federation.
And you're right again, in the episode "The hunted" we clearly see the investigations are not very thorough...

Comment: So, you please me with your answers, but the main question stand. That's why I can't validate your response :\

Comment: @GBMan I suspect there may be text in the very influential 1975 book the Starfleet Technical Manual by Franz Joseph which should have some version of principles and rights.  But purely canon sources don't exist.  In TOS the Federation would be quite eager to let a planet with Dilithium in.  See "Journey to Babel" or for a lesser trade deal "Mirror, Mirror".  I suspect the Federation will tolerate a lot as long as it doesn't make them look bad and any joining planet can choose their level of involvement.   My opinion not an answer.   Best wishes.

Comment: This answer would be much improved with some quotes and references.